# jq create array and append entry to it

Tags: bash, jq

I want to produce json file with structure like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "Edinburgh"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Tokyo"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is my bash script:

```
list=( http://RESTURL1 http://RESTURL2 )

jq -n .data[] > result.json ## -> (create empty array data)

for p in $list

VAR1=$(curl $p | jq -r .foo ) ## -> (Tiger Nixon)
VAR2=$(curl $p | jq -r .bar ) ## -> (Edinburgh)

cat result.json | jq -n --arg a "$VAR1" --arg b "$VAR2"  .data["$a","$b"] >> results.json ## -> (add Tiger Nixon and Edinburgh to .data array)

done
```

Script is selfexplaining. Except jq part. I dont know how to handle jq to create json file.

Basically I want to iterate over list of urls, populate 2 variables and push it to results.json file as entry/per iteration.

Thanks

Comment: not selfexplaining. Use parentheses to create a bash array: `list=( url1 url2 )`. Show the (hypothetical) return data from the curl call. Is it something like `{"foo":"Garrett Winters","bar":"Tokyo"}` ?

Comment: The script is invalid.  Since you've tagged the Q as `bash`, please revise the Q so that at least it is syntactically correct.  Also, please try to adhere more closely to the mcve guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added hyphotetical data from curl. Of course it is invalid.. Because I do not know how to do it properly

Comment: You can't have `.foo` as a value and also as an object that contains `.bar`. Show the hypothetical *raw JSON* from the curl code that you need to parse.

Comment: Problem is line 3 and 10, every other line is fine for me (working)

Comment: The extent to which we complain about "invalid" is the same sense in which the "correct" in [mcve] requires that a script be correct -- the only error it should have is *the specific error you're asking about*; in every other respect, someone should be able to run it themselves (letting them, for example, test their fixes). In the same manner, something that can't be run without a URL you don't provide isn't "verifiable"; it has bugs unrelated to your uncertainties about JQ.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, `cat foo | bar` is better written as `<foo bar` or `bar <foo`; that way you're directly connecting to `bar` process to its `foo` input file, instead of connecting `foo` to a copy of `/bin/cat`, connecting the output of `/bin/cat` to a FIFO, and then connecting the other side of the FIFO to `bar`.

Comment: The script is ALSO invalid because the "do" required in "for ... ; do ...; done" is missing.

Answer (score 4):

Reusing Glenn's test framework, but calling `jq` only once for the entire script:

```
list=( http://RESTURL1 http://RESTURL2 )

declare -A hypothetical_data=(
    [http://RESTURL1]='{"foo":"Tiger Nixon","bar":"Edinburgh"}'
    [http://RESTURL2]='{"foo":"Garrett Winters","bar":"Tokyo"}'
)

for url in "${list[@]}"; do
  echo "${hypothetical_data[$url]}"  # or curl "$url"
done | jq -n '{"data": [inputs | [.foo, .bar]]}'
```

Comment: or in this case `{"data":[inputs | [.foo, .bar]]}` -- thank Charles, I'm finding the functional nature of jq pretty hard to wrap my procedural brain around.

Comment: Oops -- I didn't pay enough attention to the desired output; thank you for the pointer. :)

Comment: There is no output to file results.json

Comment: Put `>results.json` on the end, and there you are. Call that "exercise left for the reader".

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

list=( http://RESTURL1 http://RESTURL2 )

declare -A hypothetical_data=(
    [http://RESTURL1]='{"foo":"Tiger Nixon","bar":"Edinburgh"}'
    [http://RESTURL2]='{"foo":"Garrett Winters","bar":"Tokyo"}'
)

# create the seed file
result="result.json"
echo '{"data":[]}' > "$result"

for url in "${list[@]}"; do
    # fetch the data.
    json=${hypothetical_data[$url]}
    # would really do: json=$(curl "$url")

    # extract the name ("foo") and location ("bar") values
    name=$( jq -r '.foo' <<<"$json" )
    location=$( jq -r '.bar' <<<"$json" )

    jq --arg name "$name" \
       --arg loc "$location" \
         '.data += [[$name, $loc]]' "$result" | sponge "$result"

    # "sponge" is in the "moreutils" package that you may have to install. 
    # You can also write that line as:
    #
    # tmp=$(mktemp)
    # jq --arg name "$name" \
    #    --arg loc "$location" \
    #      '.data += [[$name, $loc]]' "$result" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$result"
    #                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
done
```

End result:

```
$ cat result.json
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "Edinburgh"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Tokyo"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to *write* the file using jq?

```
list=( http://RESTURL1 http://RESTURL2 )

exec > result.json    

echo '['

for p in "${list[@]}"
    data=$(curl "$p")
    echo "  $(jq -c '[.foo, .bar]' <<< "$data"),"
done

echo ']'
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: how do you call jq only once?

Comment: Updated, calling jq only once per url

Comment: JSON really does not like trailing commas in a list.

Comment: As @glennjackman has stated, this code does not produce valid JSON.